# Show calendar for date/time report parameter

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, parameters, dynamics-crm-2011, prompt

I have a Report parameter of type "Date/Time".

In Visual Studio the parameter prompt has a calendar for the user to choose a date. But when I run the report from CRM, the date parameter is simply shown as a textbox and the user has to write the date manually.

I need to show a calendar for the datetime parameter in CRM 2011

[image: Report Viewer CRM vs VS]

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to  be a browser problem. I was using Chrome. The date picker appeared in Internet Explorer and Firefox